# Boolean checks in SPARQL, check for existence of a statement

Tags: boolean, rdf, sparql, semantic-web

Let's say I have a triple store full of video metadata. A video can have an arbitrary selection of pre-defined tags, like this:

```
v1 ex:hasTag A.
v2 ex:hasTag B.
v3 ex:hasTag A;
   ex:hasTag B.
```

So for the sake of this example, there are only the two pre-defined tags `A` and `B`.

Now I would like to get an overview of which video has which tags attached, in a matrix like this (or similar):

```
    A     B 

v1  true  false
v2  false true
v3  true  true
```

However, I do not know how to achieve this. First of all, I would need a boolean test, e.g. something like `isTrue(?video ex:hasTag A)` or whatever it looks like. Even then, I do not know where to put it. If I put the previous statement in the WHERE clause, the query result only contains the videos having the tag `A`, of course.

Coming from SQL, I can imagine I need to use subqueries in some way, [but these seem not to be standardized at the moment](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql-features/#Subqueries). I also saw the [`FILTER`](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/#scopeFilters) keyword, but I don't feel that is what I want.

I'm currently at a loss but always willing to learn. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try starting with something like this:

```
SELECT ?video ?tagA ?tagB {
  ?video a ex:Video .
  OPTIONAL { ?video ex:hasTag ?tagA . FILTER (?tagA = "A") }
  OPTIONAL { ?video ex:hasTab ?tagB . FILTER (?tagB = "B") }
}
```

That will you roughly what you want. If you really must have boolean values rather than simple checking for unbound vals use:

```
SELECT ?video (bound(?tagA) as ?a) (bound(?tagB) as ?b) { ... }
```

P.S. Subqueries are (very nearly, proposed recommendation at time of writing) [standardised in SPARQL 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#subqueries).

Answer (score 7):

Subqueries are in SPARQL 1.1 and that is frozen now.  There several complete implementations already.

As well as nested-SELECT subqueries, SPARQL 1.1 has the EXISTS and NOT EXISTS functions for testing whether a pattern matches or not.  It#'s a form of subquery.  You can use it in a FILTER or if you really want to return true/false:

```
BIND(EXISTS{?video ex:hasTag "A"} AS ?a)
```

or even:

```
SELECT ?video (EXISTS{?video ex:hasTag "A"} AS ?a) (EXISTS{?video ex:hasTag "B"} AS ?b)
{           
  ?video a ex:Video .
}
```

Comment: Using EXISTS, what if I want to check multiple values like `EXISTS(?video ex:hasTag ("A" || "B")}`

Comment: It's a full pattern: `EXISTS{ ?video ex:hasTag ?X . FILTER (?X IN ("A" , "B"))}`